# How to mix Pug/Jade with Django conditionals and html element attributes?

Tags: django, django-templates, pug, templatetags

I want to write Django conditionals for html attributes, like

```
<a {% if item.link %} href="{{ item.link }}", target="_blank", rel="noopener", aria-label="{{ item }}" {% endif %}>
     --- Content ---
</a>
```

I am using pug/jade, so I can't put jade/pug syntax inside "Content" block, the compiler breaks. **I would like to know if I can handle that in any way to no repeat the "Content" block.**

I tried also, withouth success:

```
a({% if item.link %} href="{{ item.link }}", target="_blank", rel="noopener", aria-label="{{ item }}" {% endif %})
      ----Content---
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like PyPugJS? https://github.com/kakulukia/pypugjs

Comment: looked around, but don't see where that package solves my question...

Comment: It's a system for writing pug that compiles to django syntax. You write pug conditionals that get translated into django conditionals. I don't think you're going to find a good way to use them both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to achieve this. Incredibly the solution is very simple and I felt a little dumb when I found it:

```
<a {% if item.link %} href="{{ item.link }}", target="_blank", rel="noopener", aria-label="{{ item }}" {% endif %}>
--- Content ---
</a>
```

Just need to put the *--- Content ---* block in the same indentation level as the plain html content.